# CLLocationManager - Calculate real time speed on iPhone

Tags: ios, real-time, cllocationmanager

How can I calculate real time speed on device? I've googled a lot but all I got is to calculate distance and speed after completion of journey. Can I calculate speed at runtime?

Suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here `CLLocationManager` class provide different field of location like, Latitude, Longitude,accuracy and speed.

i use `CoreLocationController` so for location update i call this bellow method
you can get current speed in **- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location**  method like bellow

```
  - (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location
{
     NSString *currentspeed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SPEED: %f", [location speed]];
}
```

or otherwise bellow is delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"in update to location");
    NSString *currentspeed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SPEED: %f", [newLocation speed]];
}
```

also you can get example from this link...
http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/

i hope this help you...
:)

Comment: Sir,i've read that link and also have tried it,but its not completing my purpose(not getting acurate or nearly accurate speed)...

Comment: ok just try this one http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/

Comment: also this iOS sdk example i use this with my own way like CoreLoactionController... use this also.... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thank u sir... am trying it. Can u please suggest me any way on the  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107866/distance-between-two-gps-locations-and-also-trace-a-route-line-between-them)

Answer (score 0):

There is a delegate `CLLocationManagerDelegate` add it to your controller header file.

Initialize Location Manager and set the delegate where you implement the delegate method for location Manager like this

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self; // send loc updates to current class
```

and you can write method in your class

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"Location Speed: %f", newLocation.speed);
}
```

That's it you will get your location updates in the above method with the speed also, and it will trigger as frequent as possible.

Comment: There's another very good complete example  here
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/18209-crazy-speed-gps-myclcontroller-corelocation.html

Comment: @Adeel.... Autometic reference counting is enabled in my program,so...its showing error message "delegate property must be unsafe_unretained "

Comment: That delegate method has been deprecated.