# Distance between two GPS locations and also trace a route line between them

Tags: ios, gps

i tried to find distance between two GPS locations and i got the way using MKReverseGeocoder... now,how can i trace a path between those two locations.. suggestions will be highly appreciated..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: you means draw the path between two location??

Comment: hello mate just try to learn bellow example https://github.com/wlach/nvpolyline here you find easily your target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and for distance from two location just use bellow line to get distance

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [yourCurrentLocation distanceFromLocation:yourDestinationLocation];
```

here yourCurrentLocation and yourDestinationLocation is CLLocation variable 
and  It Returns the distance (in meters) from the receiver’s location to the specified location.

i hope this helpful to you..
:)

Comment: @Paras.. i did this,and i can also get the destinations address through GPS.. but now am trying to trace a road map between these two locations.

Comment: also see this https://github.com/route-me/route-me and for above example just create array with your current route and initwith your array on NVPolyline class.. now just try to understand that code.. you get your output .. :)